# Login WebApp contra Active Directory .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Tengo una web app hecha en .NET, y cuando hago el deploy en la Pool del dominio, puedo hacer login (contra AD, no Azure).

Pero si lo hago desde localhost (máquina de desarrollo) me dice lo siguiente.

> Error authenticating. Error obtaining group names. El dominio especificado no existe o no se pudo poner en contacto con él.

Hay algo que estoy haciendo mal? He leído que puede ser el puerto 389, que tendría que abrir, es así?

Un saludo,
Christian